# Local Storage Bug for React, NextJS & Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, local-storage

I have an app that im working on that has a bug for storing data on a browsers local storage, the variables do get sent to the browsers local storage but every time I refresh the page, the local storage variables reset.

I tried looking at redux docs , tried using mobx however I reverted back to Redux and think it can be solved in Redux, I feel like there's something small thats missing.

Here is the function code :

```
export default function MyFunction() {

    // Config object
    const settings = {
        apiKey: API_KEY, // env variable
        network: Network.ETH_GOERLI
    };
    const alchemy = new Alchemy(settings);

    const contractAddress = CONTRACT_ADDRESS //env variable

    let loggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.user.isLoggedIn);
    let owner = useSelector((state) => state.user.walletAddress);
    let nfts = useSelector((state) => state.user.nfts);


    const [storeNft, setStoreNft] = useLocalStorage("storeNft", nfts.toString());
    const [storeOwner, setStoreOwner] = useLocalStorage("storeOwner", owner);
    const [storeLoggedIn, setStoreLoggedIn] = useLocalStorage("storeLoggedIn", loggedIn);




    const [pageContent, setPageContent] = useState("An error Occured");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    // const initialRender = useRef(true);


    //This function populates the nft array once we have found usurpa nfts 
    async function getNftsForOwner() {
        const _nfts = [];
        try {
            // Get the async iterable for the owner's NFTs.
            const nftsIterable = alchemy.nft.getNftsForOwnerIterator(owner);

            // Iterate over the NFTs and add them to the nfts array.
            for await (const nft of nftsIterable) {
                if (nft.contract.address == contractAddress.toLowerCase()) {
                    _nfts.push(nft);

                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        dispatch(setNfts(_nfts));
    }

    async function signedHandler() {

        if (!window.ethereum) {

            setPageContent(
                "Install Metamask in your browser"
            )

        } else {
            if (window.ethereum.isConnected()) {
                await getNftsForOwner()
                setPageContent(
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <a>
                               NFT Viewer
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a>
                                Your NFT Collection :
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <NftList nfts={nfts} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            } else {
                setPageContent(
                    "Connect Wallet"
                )

            }
        }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
    
        setStoreNft(JSON.stringify(nfts));
        setStoreOwner(JSON.stringify(owner));
        setStoreLoggedIn(JSON.stringify(loggedIn));
        signedHandler();

    }, [nfts, owner, loggedIn, storeNft, storeOwner, storeLoggedIn]);

    return (
        <div>
            {pageContent}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue with your local storage is that you are initializing the local storage values with the current values of your Redux state every time the component renders. This means that when the page is refreshed, the values stored in local storage are immediately replaced with the current state values, resulting in the appearance of the variables resetting.

To fix this, you need to initialize the local storage values only once, when the component first mounts. You can achieve this by using the useEffect hook with an empty dependency array [], which means the effect will only run once when the component mounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
setStoreNft(JSON.stringify(nfts));
setStoreOwner(JSON.stringify(owner));
setStoreLoggedIn(JSON.stringify(loggedIn));
}, []);
```

This way, the local storage values will be set only once, when the component mounts, and not every time the component renders.

Also, when you retrieve the values from local storage, you should parse the JSON string back into its original value type:

```
const [storeNft, setStoreNft] = useLocalStorage("storeNft", JSON.parse(nfts.toString()));
const [storeOwner, setStoreOwner] = useLocalStorage("storeOwner", 
JSON.parse(owner));
const [storeLoggedIn, setStoreLoggedIn] = useLocalStorage("storeLoggedIn", 
JSON.parse(loggedIn));
```

With these changes, your local storage variables should persist across page refreshes.